# Any UI automation cmdlet is planned in Powershell V3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have searched to find way to automate GUI using powershell and come across with some good online sources. But they are all using custom cmdlet. As new version of powershell is in progress, Is there any new cmdlet are availed for GUI automation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there will be anything specifically for UI automation.

I made a [blog post](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com/2011/09/new-commands-in-powershell-v3-from.html) with all of the new commands in the Windows 8 developer preview. Nothing for UI automation. You can download the current version CTP 2 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27548) and check it out.

You'll probably still have to rely on third party stuff. Like [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

UI automation is very much subjective to the framework and other aspects of UI development. So, I don't expect PowerShell core to support anything like that. There are, however, community extensions to do a limited set of UI automation. As Andy points out, WASP is one of them. There are a few articles on MSDN around UI automation using PowerShell such as this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx.