# Use Powershell to highlight files on an open file explorer window

Tags: powershell

I've seen how to open a *new* File explorer, e.g. `explorer.exe /select,$path` and select files in that new window, but how would I do this with an *existing* File explorer window, i.e. tell File explorer to select certain files, as if the user had clicked and highlighted those files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any UI automation cmdlet is planned in Powershell V3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784552/any-ui-automation-cmdlet-is-planned-in-powershell-v3-0)

Answer (score 2):

I love Powershell, honestly I use it even when I know another language would be better. But this is no job for Powershell. I don't know to what end, you are "selecting files" in Explorer for, but it may be possible to accomplish your end goal without utilizing the GUI. If for some reason I don't understand you actually want to do what your are asking about in your question, I would use [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com) to simulate key presses or clicks.

Comment: Or the [AutoIt PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/).